# Is it possible to have multiple top level domain in android manifest host declaration?

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using firebase dynamic link to add deep link to my app, and that website has multiple domains, i.e.

- www.foo.com
- www.foo.net
- www.foo.co.uk
- www.foo.kp
- and more ...

I saw that in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#host it says that astrid must be the first character of the host. Is there any solution to work around this? I would like to see if it is possible to add more domain without the need to update the app.

Comment: Yes, you must declare them all in the AndroidManifest file though.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible to 'work around' this.** This is for security reasons.

Here's why: subdomains are all under the control of the main domain. If you are able to verify `example.com`, by definition you could also verify `example1.example.com`. The `*` wildcard in the Manifest is simply a convenience shortcut, though you still need to handle the server component of the verification separately for each subdomain.

In contrast, `example.com` and `example.co.uk` are *totally separate domains*. There is no guarantee that the owner of one will also be the owner of the other.

Also worth noting: Firebase Dynamic Links does not support white labelled domains. You may *also* be using Dynamic Links, but you'll need to implement all of this yourself. [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) does support white labelling, though only of a single domain per app.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't hit you too much in this specific case. The actual dynamic link (as Alex notes) is on the APPCODE.app.goo.gl subdomain. That's the URL which redirects to your app or the Play store/App store. As part of that you need to resolve to a specific domain your app claims, but you don't really need to support all possible domains: you choose which regular link you're going to wrap in a dynamic link when you generate it.

I appreciate that separately you'll want to have your app respond to regular App Link/Universal Link taps on your own URLs - these wont be dynamic links, and you'll have to update your app to handle them explicitly.